# Left alignment of the "content" property but right alignment of the actual content of the div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, text-alignment

I have a box with a fixed width and would like to left align the dollar sign but right align the amount.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dollarAmount">80,500</div>
<div class="dollarAmount">1,150,000</div>
```

**css**

```
.dollarAmount:before {content: "$ ";text-align:left}
.dollarAmount{width:80px;border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:right}
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kq5jth1/1/embedded/result)

Thanks

Comment: Direct link to edit JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kq5jth1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your before content to float left instead of text-align.

Here's how it should look:

```
.dollarAmount{width:80px;border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:right}
.dollarAmount:before {content: "$ ";float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just float the dollar sign:

`.dollarAmount:before {content: "$ ";float:left}`